# Query Database Objective-c don't insert new values

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

On my project, I create a new database form puglin firefox:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    sqlite3 *db;

    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"registros.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    int resultado = sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db);


    if(success == true){
         NSLog(@"The database Reconized File Exist");

    }

    if(resultado == SQLITE_OK){

        NSLog(@"The sql is open");

    }

    char *sql = "INSERT INTO campos (campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;


    int resultado2 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);

    if(resultado2 == SQLITE_OK){

        NSLog(@"The prepare is execute");

    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [@"Campo_01" UTF8String], -1, nil);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [@"Campo_02" UTF8String], -1, nil);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [@"Campo_03" UTF8String], -1, nil);

    resultado2 = sqlite3_step(stmt);

    if(resultado2 == SQLITE_DONE){

        NSLog(@"Sql Done");
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);


}
```

The four logs on console is showing to me, but in my database, don't have any new values, the fields are ok, the name of my database are ok too, so why insert doesn't work?

Comment: The fifth parameter to [sqlite3_bind_text](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) should not be `nil`, but that value happens to be identical with SQLITE_STATIC.

Comment: I'm beginner and I don't understand what you say, I try in the  fifth parameter to sqlite3_bind_text change 'nil' to 'SQLITE_STATIC', and doesn't work too....

Comment: The fifth parameter must be either a function or SQLITE_STATIC or SQLITE_TRANSIENT. `nil` is just a misleading way of writing SQLITE_STATIC, so that change did not have an actual effect, except that the value is no longer misleading. (The rest of your code looks OK.)